# Writing to and reading plain text files with writelines() and readlines()

Tags: python, list, readlines

I understand what these functions do, but what would be the practical use of reading/writing some as a list, and what is the use of writing a list to a file, if you could just use `write()` and then later use `readlines()` to view it as a list?

Comment: if you already have a list it saves you a trivial step ...

Comment: but if you try and read it using read() doesnt it still return the elements but not in list format? so you would still need readlines() in order to read it as a list, i believe?

Comment: or just split the text once you get it ... its a pretty trivial step to be honest ... and most of the time not super applicable

Answer (score 1):

The practical upside of writing data to disk is that you can drop it from your system memory and come back to it later.

Comment: +1 if thats actually his question ... way to read between the lines ... thats not what I got from reading the question

Answer (score 0):

`.writelines()` accepts any iterable that produces strings. It could be implemented as:

```
def writelines(self, lines):
    for line in lines:
        self.write(line)
```

If you call `file.writelines(["abc", "def"])` then the file will contain: `abcdef`. And `file.readlines()` would return `["abcdef"]` if you read it back. As you see the roundtrip produces different result.

If you call `file.write(["abc", "def"])` then you get `TypeError: must be string or buffer, not list`. Again it is different.